# Не работает my-account в woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Модуль Woocommerce 'my-account' не работает через автоматическую созданную страницу "Мой аккаунт". Шорткод вставлен, но страничка пустая. Однако если создать шаблон под "Мой аккаунт" файлом php и вставить

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]') ?>
```

То модуль начинает работать. Но пункты меню в личном кабинете ведут снова на пустые страницы. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: что значит "если создать шаблон под "Мой аккаунт" файлом php" ?

Comment: Нет такого модуля. Если не работают шорткоды проверяй отключением плагинов и сменой темы

Comment: У вас страница не выводит контент, вот и все) Попробуйте в админке написать простой текст, его ведь тоже не будет?

Comment: @WPPunk Все верно, страница page.php не выводила контент. Теперь все отлично, спасибо)